# What does a porcupine have to do with a berit milah?

Tags: shabbat, jewish-books, animals, brit-milah, symbols-symbology

[image: Porcupine in Rothschild Miscellany]

[R' Natan Slifkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natan_Slifkin), in [this](http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2014/06/prickly-problems-and-design-dilemmas.html) recent blog post, presents the above-embedded picture of a porcupine from the [Rothschild Miscellany](http://www.facsimile-editions.com/en/rm/) (Italy, 15th Century CE), which adorns a *yotzer* (seasonal additional prayer-poem) that's said when a [*berit milah*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brit_milah) is performed on *Shabbat*. He is wondering what the intention of the illustrator was: What does a porcupine have to do with a *berit milah*?

Comment: Hatafat Dam Berit?

Comment: @DoubleAA, maybe. But that, in particular, wouldn't be done on Shabbat, would it?

Comment: What does a bird have to do with milah?

Comment: @sam, Perhaps worthy of a separate question, especially if you can first identify the pictured bird. The porcupine appears to be the primary subject of the illustration, though.

Comment: In Hebrew a porcupine is a דרבנתי which interestingly has the letters of Bris in it.

Comment: It might have to do with what's written,I can't make out the words to blurry

Comment: +1 for an interesting question. I never even knew that anyone said Yotzros on a Shabbos Bris Milah. I can’t find any texts online, either, and I can’t make out the calligraphy in the attached image. Do you have a plain text version of this piyut that I can look over?

Comment: Apparently, a porcupine appears at least one other time in the book. See [here](https://twitter.com/RobbinsLibUR/status/1070717202502963200/photo/1). I also had a theory that it might be related to "ואליבא דרבי אליעזר דאמר מכשירי מילה דוחין את השבת. ורבינו סובר *דרבן* שמעון בן גמליאל", Derabban can be also pronounced Dorban (porcupine) and this might be some kind of play on words, but that might not fit with this other image.

Comment: It may jus be because it looks nice.